# CSS Full Height Sidebar

Tags: html, css

I've been researching for hours trying to figure out this issue. I want to display sidebar with 100% height responsively **without** *position: fixed/absolute*, is this possible to do it?

```css
.sidebar {
    height: 100%;
    width: 40%;
    border-right: none;
    background: blue;
}
```

```html
<div class="sidebar">
  <p class="menu-section-head text-left">MENU UTAMA</p>
  <nav class="sidebar-nav">
  <ul>
      <li>
          <span>Menu 1</span>
          <hr class="underline">
     </li>
     <li>
          <span>Menu 2</span>
          <hr class="underline">
     </li>
     <li>
          <span>Menu 3</span>
          <hr class="underline">
     </li>
  </ul>
  </nav>
</div>
```

Comment: `body, html {height: 100%}`

Comment: This is a pretty common design pattern. Your code is incomplete as you need it to be 100% of something, e.g. its parent. Look into flexbox for the parent, or ancestors if you need to go that far.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Use 100vh in place 100% in height.

```css
.sidebar {
    height: 100vh;
    width: 40%;
    border-right: none;
    background: blue;
}
```

```html
<div class="sidebar">
  <p class="menu-section-head text-left">MENU UTAMA</p>
  <nav class="sidebar-nav">
  <ul>
      <li>
          <span>Menu 1</span>
          <hr class="underline">
     </li>
     <li>
          <span>Menu 2</span>
          <hr class="underline">
     </li>
     <li>
          <span>Menu 3</span>
          <hr class="underline">
     </li>
  </ul>
  </nav>
</div>
```

Comment: Always Welcome @newITguy

Answer (score 1):

does switching from 100% to 100vh (viewer height) accomplish what you are looking for? % mimics the parent contianer, vh uses the window.

```css
.sidebar {
    height: 100vh;
    width: 40%;
    border-right: none;
    background: blue;
}
```

```html
<div class="sidebar">
  <p class="menu-section-head text-left">MENU UTAMA</p>
  <nav class="sidebar-nav">
  <ul>
      <li>
          <span>Menu 1</span>
          <hr class="underline">
     </li>
     <li>
          <span>Menu 2</span>
          <hr class="underline">
     </li>
     <li>
          <span>Menu 3</span>
          <hr class="underline">
     </li>
  </ul>
  </nav>
</div>
```